# SpreadsheetLight C# - data selection

Tags: c#, charts, line, selection, spreadsheetlight

I want to select the data in the table, as below:
http://zapodaj.net/e8bd4193a1811.png.html

column Date(column B) and column Monthly Invoice(excl. Vat)(column M)

How?

```
chart = sl.CreateChart("B3", "M15");
chart.SetChartType(SLLineChartType.Line);
chart.SetChartPosition(19, 1, 15 + fChartHeight, 1 + fChartWidth);
gdloptions = chart.CreateGroupDataLabelOptions();                          
gdloptions.ShowValue = true;               
chart.SetGroupDataLabelOptions(11, gdloptions);         
sl.InsertChart(chart);`
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Did you find how to do this?